# Is there an easy example of $\Delta_1$ property?

Tags: logic, set-theory

A property $P$ is $\Delta_1$ if $P$ is equivalent to formulas of the forms $\exists x\varphi$ and $\forall x\phi$ where $\varphi$ and $\phi$ are $\Delta_0$, meaning that all variables in $\varphi$ are bounded.

Can anyone please provide me an easy example of $\Delta_1$ property, and explain it to me why it is $\Delta_1$?

Comment: $\forall x (x = 0)$ is $\Delta_1$. This is because $x = 0$ is $\Delta_0$ and $\forall x (x = 0)$ is of the form $\forall x \phi$ where $\phi := (x = 0)$ is a $\Delta_0$ statement.

Comment: My bad... I should have said "and" instead of "or" in the first line describing $\Delta_1$. Please see the edit.

Comment: Ok, then $\forall x (x = 0)$ is still $\Delta_1$ because it's equivalent to $\exists x (x \neq x)$, which is $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: Mark's examples with no free variables seem somewhat uninteresting - my understanding is that when we talk about the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) we're usually talking about formulas with at least one free variable (so that each formula defines e.g. a set of natural numbers).

Comment: How about '$n$ is an even number'? It should be easy to find a sentence $\varphi$ such that $n$ is even is exactly the statement $\exists x\lt n.\varphi(x,n)$; with a little more thought you should be able to find a sentence $\phi$ such that $n$ is even is the statement $\forall x\lt n.\phi(x,n)$. (Consider that '$n$ is even' is the same as '$n$ is not odd' and then move the negation past the quantifier).

Comment: Jech's example (Lemma 13.11 of "Set Theory" 3rd Millenium Ed.): "$E$ is a well-founded relation on $A$" is a $\Delta_1$ property. The standard definition is clearly $\Pi_1$: for all $X$, if $\emptyset \ne X \subseteq A$ then there's an $x\in X$ that is $E$-minimal. The property is also $\Sigma_1$ because $(A, E)$ is well-founded if any only if there is an order-preserving function $f\colon (A,E) \to (\operatorname{Ord}, \in)$. This last statement about $f$ is actually $\Delta_0$: it just says "$f$ is ordinal-valued, and for all $a, b\in A$, if $a E b$ then $f(a)\in f(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some computable enumeration of the primitive recursive functions $P_0, P_1, \ldots$. Consider the statement "$P_n(n) = 0$". This is a statement which is $\Delta_1$ (since $\{n \mid P_n(n) = 0\}$ is recursive) but which is not $\Delta_0$, since by a basic diagonalisation argument, the statement $P_n(n) = 0$ is not primitive recursive.

Specifying the diagonal argument more precisely:

Suppose that the predicate $n \mapsto P_n(n) = 0$ is primitive recursive. Take $k$ such that $P_k(n) = 0$ if and only if $P_n(n) = 0$.

Define $f(n) = \max(0, 1 - P_k(n))$. Then $f$ is primitive recursive; take $j$ such that $P_j = f$.

Suppose $P_j(j) = 0$. Then $P_k(j) \neq 0$. Then $P_j(j) \neq 0$. Contradiction. Therefore, $P_j(j) \neq 0$. Then $P_k(j) = 0$. Then $P_j(j) = 0$. Contradiction.

So the predicate $n \mapsto P_n(n) = 0$ must not be primitive recursive.

But recall that every $\Delta_0$ predicate is primitive recursive. So the predicate $n \mapsto P_n(n) = 0$ is not $\Delta_0$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that the primitive recursive functions are computably enumerable?

Comment: @Karl Primitive recursive functions can be encoded as strings, which can in turn be encoded as numbers. It should be pretty straightforward to implement a computable "interpreter" function that takes the number of a primitive recursive function, together with the number of an input, and calculates the output.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. If I understand correctly, we're using the fact that we can check a program representation for primitiveness "syntactically" (in time bounded by program size), so that the set of Godel numbers of primitive recursive functions is computable. We can't say the same thing about e.g. the set of Godel numbers of total computable functions, even though they admit a similar "interpreter".

Comment: @Karl Yes, that is correct. Note that our enumeration will contain repeats, since we can't decide whether two primitive recursive function representations give the same primitive recursive function. But that's ok; the only thing that matters is that we get all the primitive recursive functions at least once.

Comment: Incidentally, in an attempt to answer my own question, I found [this article](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/smk/primrec.pdf), which says we can in fact enumerate the p.r. functions without semantic duplicates. But I'm glad it's easier if we allow duplicates.

Comment: @Karl I see, that makes sense. I hadn't thought of it that way. So we actually could get rid of the duplicates. But there's no need to for this proof.

Comment: Since this is tagged [set-theory], I'd imagine we're talking about the Levy hierarchy, not the arithmetic hierarchy (which would be $\Delta^0_1$ in most places).

Comment: @Karl Note that the paper describes a computable enumeration of the primitive recursive functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to PrimRec$ which is also a bijection. It can be shown constructively that $f$ is a total computable function and is injective, but it cannot be shown constructively that $f$ is a surjection.

Comment: This is an "easy example", illustrating some essential properties of $\Delta_1$?